# How to redirect a page when preessed ok button of custom alert box in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Here is my javascript code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    Alert.render('Saved!','myurl.php');
 </script>
```

and the render function is

```
function CustomAlert() {
this.render = function (dialog,url) {
    var winW = window.innerWidth;
    var winH = window.innerHeight;
    var dialogoverlay = document.getElementById('dialogoverlay');
    var dialogbox = document.getElementById('dialogbox');
    dialogoverlay.style.display = "block";
    dialogoverlay.style.height = winH + "px";
    dialogbox.style.left = (winW / 2) - (550 * 0.5) + "px";
    dialogbox.style.top = "100px";
    dialogbox.style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById('dialogboxhead').innerHTML = "Heading";
    document.getElementById('dialogboxbody').innerHTML = dialog;
    document.getElementById('dialogboxfoot').innerHTML = "<button class='btn btn-info' onclick='Alert.ok(\"" + url + "\")'>OK</button>";
}
this.ok = function (url) {
    window.location.href(url);
    document.getElementById('dialogbox').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('dialogoverlay').style.display = "none";
}
}
var Alert = new CustomAlert();
```

my problem is the page is not redirecting after clicking the 'Ok' button. Please help me??

Comment: In my Customalert function, I am displaying ok button and I have triggering the onclick function

Comment: very helpful for problems like this is pressing the F12 key on your keyboard. The console will tell you exactly the first line of @cerlinBoss answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`window.location.href` is not a function

change `window.location.href(url);` to `window.location.href = url;`

Comment: are you sure the `Alert.ok` function is getting called?

Comment: Please check my code. I am calling it in button with onclick function

Comment: yeah we saw that. put some alert or console.log to check if the function is called properly. or check the console if thr s any errors

Comment: My mistake. After the above change it worked. I have cleared all web history and then refreshed the page. Now it is working. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

change

`onclick='Alert.ok(\"" + url + "\")'>`

to

`onclick='this.ok(\"" + url + "\")'>`

because Alert in undefined within the scope of `CustomAlert`

Comment: `this` when used on the onclick attribute will reference the button element and not the Alert